# Unique index for User.username in django-nonrel mongodb?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I'm building an application in django-nonrel with mongoDB as the backend.  I've been trying to use the out-of-the box User authentication system, but I keep running into weirdness.

The latest problem is creating users.  When I call User.objects.create_user, there doesn't seem to be any validation for uniqueness.  I can create **more than one user with the exactly same username**.  I had expected that username would enforce a unique index, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

If this were one of my own models, I'd try adding "unique=True" in the model, then syncing the DB to implement the index.  Since I'm using a built-in model, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Another possibility might be to hard-code syncdb to add the index.  That seems kludgy, though.   What's the best way to go forward here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`username` already has `unique=True`. You need to run `syncdb` in order to install the MongoDB indices.